# iframe refreshes main page

Tags: iframe, hyperlink

I am currently using a iframe on my main web page.  When i click on a link in the iframe I would like it to display the content on the main web page.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Set the `target="_parent"` on the link.

Another way would be to put this into the page that represents the content of the IFRAME:

```
<base target="_parent" />
```

Answer (score 0):

use `target='_top'` on the link in your iframe

```
<a href='http://example.com' target='_top'>My Link</a>
```

This will result in the full window/tab of the browser being replaced with the content of the link.  You could also use `_parent` as the value of the `target` attribute.  That would result in the immediate parent of the iframe being replaced which may be what you want.  It's possible though for iframes to be nested, so if `a.html` contains `b.html`, which contains `c.htm`l, a `_top` link in `c.html` would replace the entire page (`a.html`), but a target of `_parent` would only replace `b.html`.

Comment: Yes it will. At least in WebKit (Chrome/Safari) and Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with iframes in ages, but I believe it's just `<a href="myLink.html" target="_parent" />`